# How to send this form using SMTP and VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

My code was .... But it only send one field value to email .... I want multiple values to be send as it is in mail ... like ..

```
Category :
Your name :
Email ID
Mobile no. etc..
```

All form values will be transferred to mail ID ...

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
    Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("bus@volvobusesindia.com", "pink&777")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "mail.volvobusesindia.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox12.Text)
            mail.To.Add("bus@volvobusesindia.com")
            mail.Subject = "New Bus Booking Query"
            mail.Body = "Category :" & " " & DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an urge to **YELL ALL THE TIME**?

Comment: And what exactly is your question / your problem?? Do you get an error - if yes: **what** error? Does it send an e-mail but empty?? What's going on??

Comment: i m in confusion ....i dont know how to sen this form exactly as it is in email id ..... with the field mentioned above ...

Comment: as you see that ..this code i described above only send the Category value to mail ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
        mail.Body = "Category:" & " " & DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text
```

You send only the category, you need to add the other information to the Body.

I do not know the names of the fields on your form but you need to change it to something like this:

```
        mail.Body = "Category:" & " " & DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "<br>" + "Name: " + txtName.Text
```

Comment: ya you ..are right ...this will send category value ony ...but i want it send ..all the values of form fields ....as they send category ...value

Comment: THis will send the all fields in same line ..but i want it send i field per line ...

Comment: Thanks i have edited this <br> instead of <b> 

THank YOU Shiraj